# jQuery carousel with different image size

Tags: jquery, carousel

Is there any jQuery carousel that works with different width of images?

Comment: Which carousel library are you using?

Comment: http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/ - this library. I try it, but everything is fall down :(

Comment: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/autoHeight.html

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Image Scale Carousel](http://johnpatrickgiven.com/jquery/Image-Scale-Carousel/) is a carousel that works with different pictures' sizes.

> It auto scales the images you put into it to the appropriate height
>   and width keeping their aspect ratio in place.

Here is their GitHub page: https://github.com/iamjpg/jQuery-Image-Scale-Carousel