# Bootstrap caroussel fixing height but should not distort images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, styling

Here is the problem, when the window is resized to shorter in width the images start to be distorted...

The Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1juLc9ub/

The code:
HTML

```
    <div class="search-results panel-body">
    <div class="outer-listings-container row-space-8">
        <div class="row row-condensed listings-container">
            <div class="col-6 row-space-1" data-id="1">
                <div class="result">
                    <div class="panel-image listing-img">
                        <div id="1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                <div class="item active">   <a class="center-block" href="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/71832000/jpg/_71832498_71825880.jpg">
                                                <div class="center-block height-test">
                                                    <img src="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/71832000/jpg/_71832498_71825880.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block img-responsive-height">
                                                </div>
                                            </a>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>   <a class="left carousel-control height-test" id="1" href="#1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                    </a>

                        </div>
                        <div>   <a class="right carousel-control height-test" id="1" href="#1" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                    </a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .listing-img {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
.panel-image {
    position: relative;
}
.img-responsive-height {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.height-test {
    height: 350px;
}
.row-space-8 {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.row-condensed {
    margin-left: -6.25px;
    margin-right: -6.25px;
}
.listings-container > .col-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
.row-condensed > .col-1, .row-condensed > .col-2, .row-condensed > .col-3, .row-condensed > .col-4, .row-condensed > .col-5, .row-condensed > .col-6, .row-condensed > .col-7, .row-condensed > .col-8, .row-condensed > .col-9, .row-condensed > .col-10, .row-condensed > .col-11, .row-condensed > .col-12 {
    padding-left: 6.25px;
    padding-right: 6.25px;
}
.row > .col-1, .row > .col-2, .row > .col-3, .row > .col-4, .row > .col-5, .row > .col-6, .row > .col-7, .row > .col-8, .row > .col-9, .row > .col-10, .row > .col-11, .row > .col-12 {
    padding-left: 12.5px;
    padding-right: 12.5px;
}
.col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
}
.row-space-1 {
    margin-bottom: 6.25px;
}
.panel-overlay-listing-label {
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
}
.panel-overlay-label {
    background-color: rgba(121, 173, 161, 0.8);
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
}
.panel-overlay-bottom-left {
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    width: 40%;
}
.carousel {
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.a-responsive {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none;
}
.carousel-control.left {
    background-image: none;
}
.panel-body-result {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Any idea welcomed to fix that. I just want the whole image to get smaller (including the caroussel box).

Comment: try using max-width: none;

Answer (score 1):

From your code I guess you want the entire carousel to be responsive. This means that both images AND carousel need to resize depending on the available screen size.

I forked your fiddle to http://jsfiddle.net/ybsvvczh/ and changed the following:

- Removed CSS class `img-responsive-height` from HTML and CSS
- Removed CSS class `height-test` from HTML and CSS
- Removed `height: 100%;` from `.carousel`
- Added CSS class `carousel-inner` to HTML and CSS

The most relevant part is the `carousel-inner` CSS class:

```
.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's awesome! One last thing, how do I prevent it from resizing when changing the picture that does not have the same format ?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, never tried. I don't think this is a good idea, items within one carousel should always have the same dimensions. But maybe the answers in these questions may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16437166/3246440, http://stackoverflow.com/q/19055027/3246440

Comment: check out airbnb's list of results or any other agregator the box does not change size just the pic, example one is in portrait mode then it will just fit to the window.

Comment: Fixed it by setting a height of 350px in the .caroussel-inner and then a height of 100% in the .center-block